# Events fired with custom dimensions set, but google export does not have the dimensions

Tags: google-analytics, custom-dimensions

I have a website which uses GA. It does the following:

```
<html>
<head>
- Initialize GA stub
- Isogram script
<script>
ga("set", "dimension1", "abc")
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
ga("send","pageview")
</script>
...
</body>
</html>
```

I find that in test environment, or local setup, this page fires the pageview event with cd1 set.

however, on the internet, we get many events where cd1 is not being set.

I have analyzed the data and cannot find any pattern to the events where cd1 is missing. It is not specific to a browser, or device.

It also does not repro on our local machine.

Any idea what could be causing this? or... any pointers on how we can get to a root cause?

Comment: Have you tried combining the two `ga` calls into the the same script block?

Comment: Yeh.. good question. No, I havent. It is difficult to do, because it is a micro-service architecture where the head tags etc are being served from one service, and the body content from another. The service that is serving the body content will call the other service to get the head tags. Then the page view will be fired.